# Identify the graph that shows the region $x\ge 5$ and $y\ge 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I draw the equation in  wolframalpha.com but I don't know how can determine correct answer please I really need help to understand the difference:

[image]

Comment: Related, also posted by OP: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148696/please-guide-me-to-draw-this-graph-of-x-5-and-y-5 Included is a detailed answer on how to draw the graph, from which it follows how to identify the graph.

Answer (score 3):

From your image, it looks like none of your regions are shaded, but they should be; your image could have this misprint.

However, your question does ask for $x \ge 5$ and $y \ge 5$, which means the inequality is not strict. This is typically denoted by a solid line. Only choice (d) has two solid lines, one of each to represent $x \ge 5$ and $y \ge 5$.

Answer (score 2):

Here a picture that visualize the @dragon answer. The solution is the green region, including the red and blue edges .

[image]